# calling google geocode api from php getting error

Tags: php

I have used both the way to call geocode api in php, here are both way,

**my solution 1,**

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&sensor=false&key=".$google_api_key;

$resp_json = file_get_contents($url);
```

**now solution 2, is using curl,**

```
// google map geocode api url
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&sensor=false&key=".$google_api_key;

$resp_json = get_web_page($url);

// method
function get_web_page( $url, $cookiesIn = '' ){
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,     //return headers in addition to content
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,     // Validate SSL Cert
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_COOKIE         => $cookiesIn
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $rough_content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        $header_content = substr($rough_content, 0, $header['header_size']);
        $body_content = trim(str_replace($header_content, '', $rough_content));
        $pattern = "#Set-Cookie:\\s+(?<cookie>[^=]+=[^;]+)#m"; 
        preg_match_all($pattern, $header_content, $matches); 
        $cookiesOut = implode("; ", $matches['cookie']);

        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
        $header['headers']  = $header_content;
        $header['content'] = $body_content;
        $header['cookies'] = $cookiesOut;

        if($errmsg != ''){
            echo json_encode(" ERROR ". $errmsg);
        }

    return $body_content;
}
```

Now my issue is, both the solution are working on local system as well as on my linux server. but the same thing not working on another production server.

here are the errors on my both the solutions,

Error on solution 1,

**file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in**

and Error on solution 2,

**Could not resolve host: maps.googleapis.com; Name or service not known**

my google key is fine, working at my end. I am not sure what setting i have to do with cpanel.

Comment: dns issue, your machine is not resolving their address properly. if its a 'hosted' account talk to them

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cURL method, use the `file_get_contents()` method. Ensure that your production server is allowed to use the API key as well, because the issue appears to be that it's not. Unless your key is specifically set as a wild card, it won't work for multiple servers.

http://console.developers.google.com > APIs & auth > APIs > under Google Maps APIs press more > Geocoding API > enable the api and get your key so the code will be like

Comment: the api key is already enabled, the code is working well on my another server. right now its unrestricted, but i will change later.

Comment: why we should not use cURL? sorry new to php , just asking for knowledge.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of explanation on cURL, but I've had a similar DNS issue attempting to do it that way, and had success via `file_get_contents`. It's also less complicated.